# How do I install mods for Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I updated minecraft to 1.8 and the launcher to 1.5.3 and now I can't install my mods

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait for each mod to be updated to the new patch, once they are you can do a simple google search to learn how to install the latest forge version and use it to load your mods. If your mods are not updated you can adjust your version in your profile to a minecraft version that they work with.